# ¿Cómo ajustar etiquetas, y además visualizar etiquetas con los porcentajes?

Tags: matplotlib, porcentaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

### Declaramos valores para el eje y, en este caso son categorias

```
eje_x = ['Juntas de vecinos u otra organización', 'Club deportivo o recreativo', 'Organización religiosa o de iglesia', 'Agrupaciones artísticas o culturales', 'Grupos de identidad cultural', 'Agrupaciones juveniles o de estudiantes', 'Agrupaciones de mujeres', 'Agrupaciones de adulto mayor', 'Grupos de voluntariado', 'Grupos de autoayuda en salud', 'Agrupación ideológica', 'Agrupación corporativa', 'Centro de padres y apoderados', 'No participa en ninguna organización o grupo']
```

### Declaramos valores para el eje x, ahora son los valores

```
eje_y = [1967, 2092, 3110, 658, 157, 298, 293, 835, 272, 149, 198, 453, 347, 38148]
```

```
for index, value in enumerate(eje_y): 
    plt.text(value, index, 
             str(value))
```

### Creamos Gráfica y ponemos las barras de color verde

```
plt.barh(eje_x, eje_y, color="green")
```

```
plt.ylabel('Organizaciones o grupo organizado')
```

```
plt.xlabel('Participación')
```

```
plt.title('En los últimos 12 meses, ¿ha participado en alguna de las siguientes organizaciones o grupo organizado?')
```

```
plt.show()
```

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta. Dado el código que has proporcionado ¿qué salida obtienes? ¿en qué se diferencia de la que querrías obtener? ¿Puedes incluir un retoque sobre la imagen señalando qué partes querrías cambiar, para que se entienda mejor? ¿puedes también proporcionar datos de ejemplo para poder hacer pruebas, es decir, un _ejemplo mínimo verificable_?

Comment: Solo quiero agregar, además de los valores absolutos  los porcentajes de estos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modificaciones:

- Para imprimir el porcentaje, además del valor, lo más sencillo sería escribir una función que reciba el valor junto con el total (suma), y devuelva una cadena con el texto que quieres que figure en la gráfica junto a cada barra. Ese texto por ejemplo podría contener el valor absoluto junto con el porcentaje entre paréntesis (que es fácil de calcular teniendo el valor y el total).

  Entonces en el `plt.text()` que tienes en el bucle llamarías a esa función para que te genere cada etiqueta.
- Para que las etiquetas salgan algo más pequeñas (y por ejemplo de otro color) puedes definir un diccionario con atributos para la fuente, y pasarselo a `plt.text()` en un parámetro `font-dict`.
- Para que las etiquetas salgan alineadas con las barras, añade una alineación vertical centrada con el parámetro `va="center"` en `plt.text()`.
- Para que las etiquetas quepan en la gráfica, aumentamos artificialmente el valor máximo en el eje x, por ejemplo multiplicando por un factor de 1.35 el máximo.

Todo junto:

```
# @title Grafica
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Datos
eje_x = ['Juntas de vecinos u otra organización', 'Club deportivo o recreativo', 'Organización religiosa o de iglesia', 'Agrupaciones artísticas o culturales', 'Grupos de identidad cultural', 'Agrupaciones juveniles o de estudiantes', 'Agrupaciones de mujeres', 'Agrupaciones de adulto mayor', 'Grupos de voluntariado', 'Grupos de autoayuda en salud', 'Agrupación ideológica', 'Agrupación corporativa', 'Centro de padres y apoderados', 'No participa en ninguna organización o grupo']
eje_y = [1967, 2092, 3110, 658, 157, 298, 293, 835, 272, 149, 198, 453, 347, 38148]

# Atributos de fuente
font = {'family': 'sans-serif',
        'color':  '#606060',
        'weight': 'normal',
        'size': 9,
        }

# Función que crea las cadenas a usar como etiquetas
def formatear(value, total):
  return f" {value} ({value/total*100:.2f}%)"

# Poner etiquetas
total = sum(eje_y)
for index, value in enumerate(eje_y): 
    plt.text(value, index, formatear(value, total), fontdict=font, va="center")

# Pintar gráfica
plt.barh(eje_x, eje_y, color="green")
plt.ylabel('Organizaciones o grupo organizado')
plt.xlabel('Participación')
plt.title('En los últimos 12 meses, ¿ha participado en alguna de las siguientes organizaciones o grupo organizado?')

# Ampliar artificialmente el ancho para que las etiquetas quepan dentro
plt.xlim((0, max(eje_y)*1.35))

plt.show()
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda